# VueJs array data property: .includes() not finding integer value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, observable

This is no doubt down to my limited knowledge on the subject, but I can't seem to figure out how to check whether the integer value is already stored on the data property of array type.
I know the property is of the Observer type and it always seem to return `false` when asked:

```js
this.selected.includes(value)
```

Here's my complete example - please note I'm actually casting value to `Number` to ensure that all numbers are emitted as such rather than string.

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        selected: [],
      };
    },
    methods: {
      update (event) {
        const value = this.castOption(event.target.value);
        if (this.selected.includes(value)) {
          this.selected = this.selected.filter(element => element !== value);
        } else {
          this.selected.push(value);
        }
        this.$emit('input', this.selected);
      },
      castOption(value) {
        return isNaN(value) ? value : Number(value);
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

So what I'm after is a simple way to determine whether the value is already in the `selected` array.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the chrome debugger to see what it looks like inside? The `includes` function should work fine I think.

Comment: Don't use `isNaN` to determine if a variable is a number or not. It returns `false` for both `1` and `"1"`

Comment: It should return `false` for `1` and `1` because these are numbers - even if the second is wrapped in the quotes.

Comment: @Kapcash - yes I did and vue console as well - it emits correct values etc. just cannot find it in the Observer.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you saying that `this.$emit` emits the expected value? So your `.includes` actually works?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when `includes` is not working, it is because you are searching for a different object that has the same value.

Try `findIndex` and then set a breakpoint to see why the equality test fails.  Or log cases inside the loop.

You may find it is better to compare an `id` field inside your object instead of object instances.

```js
if (this.selected.findIndex(it => it === value) > -1) {
}
```

```js
if (this.selected.findIndex(it => { 
  console.log('comparing', it, value)
  return it === value
  }) > -1) {
}
```